# Validar si la contraseña viene vacio, no hacer nada

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un problema con un `controller` en `Laravel`, tengo una lista de usuarios, en el cual se puede hacer un update de cada registro.

Lo que quiero que suceda es lo siguente: Si la contraseña es un string vacio que no actualice la contraseña, osea que no la cambie, en caso contrario que si lo actualice.

Este ese el código que tengo, pero cuando le paso una cadena vacia logra entrar en la condicion. ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

```php
public function update(UserUpdate $request, User $user)
    {
        $user->update($request->all());
        if ($request->input('password') !== "") {
            $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
        }
        $user->save();
        return new UserResource($user);
    }
```

Comment: Si, pero yo luego hago una validacion, y de ese `$user` se actualiza o no nuevamente el `password.` Cuando paso un string vacio, pasa por el bloque `if`

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-when-present

Comment: Lo que debes de entender es que, en la primera línea lo estás actualizando así llegue vacío ya que update no espera hasta save para guardar los datos. Tu validación debe estar al inicio o en tu UpdateRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo te diria que intentes en vez de

```
if ($request->input('password') !== "")
```

uses

```
if ( !empty($request->input('password')) )
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Con esto solucione el problema.